# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' Nextjs version 15.5.5

Tags: next.js

Someone Help me to fix this error for Nextjs version 13.5.5

Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Help me guys i need all of u for real i spend 3 weeks on this error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGOQA.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbCwX.jpg)